# Links displaying array numbers and not mySQL values

Tags: php, mysql

As you can see on http://www.mattmaclennan.co.uk/a2 ... when you hover over "New Motorcycles", it has the array numbers, and not the labels as required. Also, the categories need to be grouped into their IDs. Below is what I have tried.

```
<?
$output = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM bikes, bikeTypes WHERE bikes.model_id = bikeTypes.model_id");
$result = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($output))
  {
    $result[] = $row;
  }
//var_dump($result);
 foreach ($result as $key => $val) {
    echo "<li><a href='test.php?id=" . $val['model_id'] . "'>".$key.'</a><ul>';
    echo "<li><a href='details.php?id=" . $val['bike_id'] . "'>" . $val['bikeName'] . "</a></li>";
    echo '</ul>';   
    echo '</li>';
  }
?>
```

The category field is called 'model'. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because you're display the $key, instead of the $value.

```
<?
$output = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM bikes, bikeTypes WHERE bikes.model_id = bikeTypes.model_id");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($output))
  {
     echo "<li><a href='test.php?id=" . $row['model_id'] . "'>".$row['???'].'</a><ul>';
     echo "<li><a href='details.php?id=" . $row['bike_id'] . "'>" . $row['bikeName'] . "</a></li>";
     echo '</ul>';   
     echo '</li>';
  }
?>
```

Comment: Hey there! thanks for the input. it has added the names successfully, but need it grouped now. I tried adding "GROUP BY bikes.model_id", but that didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean? How are you trying to display the information? GROUP BY may not be what you're looking for.